# Can we create a fixed-sized array w/o initialization

Tags: matlab

We have zeros(42,42), ones(42,42), inf(42,42), nan(42,42)...

Can we create an array w/o initialization and then fill it w/ numbers later? I know this could not be a good code that code analyzers can prove its safety. But in case an array is large, this could save some computation.

Comment: What would be the use case for something like this? If you're going to assign the values later anyway, any of these would do, wouldn't they?

Comment: @beaker, When a matrix is large, and I know I will fill them completely. creating it w/o initialization could save a bit of time. This is like what we did in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as an empty array of a fixed size. If you start filling the elements of the array later, and assign a value to element `[k1, k2]`, then you *will* have an array of size at least `[k1, k2]`, all doubles (by default). The reason is that matlab arrays are homogeneous containers, so every element has to be a proper double (or the corresponding type of the array). Sooner or later, your array has to be allocated, with zeros in case of unassigned elements. The most efficient thing to do in case of full matrices is to *preallocate*, which is what `zeros(k1max,k2max)` does. Actually, at least in older versions of MATLAB, it is faster to pre-allocate with `mymat(k1max,k2max)=0;`, i.e. by assigning a single zero to the bottom-right corner of your array (this automatically pre-allocates all the other elements between that and `[1,1]`. An other upside of pre-allocation is that MATLAB can reserve a contiguous block of memory for the whole array at once, which is the most efficient scenario possible.

What you might be looking for are *sparse* arrays. In case of large arrays with a huge number of zero elements, it's inefficient to store all those zeroes in memory, and to perform computations on them. MATLAB naturally treats [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) arrays, where only the nonzero elements are stored (for each column, so there's some overhead), which leads to huge memory efficiency and performance increase in case of very sparse matrices (where the number of nonzero elements is much smaller than the total number of elements).

An important upside of sparse matrices is that all arithmetic operations and almost all matrix operations are implemented for them, or at least they are automatically cast to full matrices. This makes their use almost identical to full matrices. And in line with your question, you only store the nonzero elements. Obviously this is only efficient if the matrix is sparse enough, otherwise the overhead from the bookkeeping of elements (and not using fully vectorized matrix operations) will make their use inefficient.

As a final remark, I just want to note that you *can* create empty double arrays as long as one of their dimensions is zero:

```
>> double.empty(100,0)

ans =

   Empty matrix: 100-by-0

>> double.empty(100,100)
Error using double.empty
At least one dimension must be zero.
```

but this rarely has a place in practical applications.

Comment: Thanks! I found we could also make a mex by http://www.mathworks.com/help/search.html?qdoc=mxcreateuninitnumericmatrix, then call it from matlab. Would this be better than mymat(k1max,k2max)=0;?

Comment: @JoeC I don't have extensive experience with MEX. However, I know this: if you have to fill the whole array, you simply can't avoid allocating every element sooner or later. If you do it later, it takes much more time and it will be less efficient. I would assume your best chance is `mymat(k1max,k2max)=0;`, as this achieves this with minimal overhead. The real question is: what makes you think allocation is any kind of bottleneck in your application? I've never heard of such a thing, with proper preallocation.

Comment: @JoeC ah I think I understand where you're coming from. Do you mean something like using `malloc`, whereas pre-allocating in matlab is equivalent to `calloc`? I'm sure that only MEX can do that, and yes, what you linked might be a good candidate. You should try and see if it works (by "works" I mean seeing what a matrix returned from that is filled with on the MATLAB side; if it's garbage, then it really is helpful). My question remains whether you expect this to be a measurable source of performance loss.

Comment: The code works on matrices with size > a few G. So I wanted to reduce the pass of iterating the data. I know this one reduces cost at constant-level. But it can still improve the response time of the calculation a little bit when data size is large.

Comment: MATLAB's performance behaves pretty different from that of lower-level languages. I strongly suggest running the built-in profiler for your actual application to see where performance bottlenecks really are. If allocation matters in the total, then you're not doing any actual calculations:)